# Remap keyboard using xmodmap but when press to change keyboard layout all settings are reset to default

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout, xmodmap

I tried to map key following this guide [How do I remap certain keys or devices?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/24916/how-do-i-remap-certain-keys). It's work for me. but one problem that I found is when I change keyboard layout (<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>) all keys will be reset to default.

How to solve this problem?

Comment: I have a similar problem. I use four layouts and my xmodmap mapping changes work on the DE and GB layout, but not on the JP and PL layout. Maybe a better question would be how xmodmap and the inbuilt GUI keyboard-layout settings work together. Also related:[xmodmap along multiple layouts](http://askubuntu.com/q/341535/231418)